# Redirect to index#tab1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This must be simple, but how can i do a redirect to http://myURL/index#tab1 without having to specify a url ?

I tried something like :

```
redirect_to :action=> 'index#tab1'
```

But it thinks it's an action and does not work (because of the # symbol actually).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
redirect_to :action => 'index', :anchor => "tab1"
```

Comment: Or *Using the new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax.*: `redirect_to action: 'index', anchor: 'tab1'`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
redirect_to 'index#tab1'
```